# Widget position in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, position

I have the following code to obtain the position of a widget within a stack:

Cubit:

```
   class StackCubit extends Cubit<Offset> {
      StackCubit()
          : super(
              Offset.zero,
            );
    
      void notifyOffsetWidget(Offset offset) {
        emit(offset);
      }
    }
```

Page:

```
class StackPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => StackCubit(),
      child: const StackContent(),
    );
  }
}

class StackContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget position'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<StackCubit, Offset>(builder: (context, state) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  OffsetReportingWidget(
                    onOffsetChanged: (offset) =>
                        context.read<StackCubit>().notifyOffsetWidget(offset),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 8,
                      width: 8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text(state.toString())
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

OffsetReportingWidget :

```
class OffsetReportingWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  /// Callback that could be executed when the widget changes its offset
  /// This callback provides the new offset through this property
  final ValueChanged<Offset>? onOffsetChanged;

  /// Creates a new OffsetReportingWidget widget.
  const OffsetReportingWidget({
    Key? key,
    required Widget child,
    this.onOffsetChanged,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  /// Creates the RenderObject that will be used to render this widget.
  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderOffsetReportingBox(
      offsetChanged: onOffsetChanged,
    ); // Uses a RenderOffsetReportingBox to report offset changes.
  }
}

/// A subclass of RenderProxyBox that adds the ability to report offset changes in a widget.
class RenderOffsetReportingBox extends RenderProxyBox {
  /// Callback that will be executed when the offset of the widget has been changed
  /// This callback is provided by the [OffsetReportingWidget]
  final ValueChanged<Offset>? offsetChanged;

  /// The previous offset of the widget that will perform layout
  Offset? _currentOffset;

  /// Constructor for the RenderOffsetReportingBox class.
  RenderOffsetReportingBox({this.offsetChanged});

  /// Method called when widget layout is being performed.
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();

    final offset = localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    
      if (offset != _currentOffset) {
        _currentOffset = offset;
        offsetChanged?.call(offset);
      }
   
  }
}
```

The problem is that the offset returned by the OffsetReportingWidget is (0.0, 0.0), however if I do a hot reload it shows the offset correctly. What is happening I think is that the offset is being returned before the widget is positioned.

Any idea how to fix it?